# SignUp rest service is not working when rest call is made from Android Application

Tags: java, android, database, fragment, android-volley

I create project in android studio and use Volley for signup and login

I can login in my android app with email and password that i insert in database with phpMyadmin But signup in android doesn't insert email and password to database!

this is my LoginDialog.java code :

```js
public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment {
    EditText edtEmail, edtPass;
    Button btnSignup, btnLogin;
    OnSignupClicked onSignupClicked;
    View view;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.login_dialog, null);
        setupViews();
        builder.setView(view);
        return builder.create();
    }



    private void setupViews() {
        btnSignup = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_loginDialog_signup);
        edtEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_loginDialog_email);
        edtPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_loginDialog_pass);
        btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_loginDialog_login);
        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();
                String pass = edtPass.getText().toString();
                userSignup(email, pass);

            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPass.getText().toString());
            }
        });


    }

    private void login(final String myEmail, final String pass) {
        String url = "http://192.168.1.101/login.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.equals("not found")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "پست الکترونیک یا رمز عبور اشتباه است", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    onSignupClicked.onClicked(response);
                    dismiss();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.i("LOG", "onErrorResponse: " + error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", myEmail);
                params.put("pass", pass);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void setOnSignupClicked(OnSignupClicked onSignupClicked) {
        this.onSignupClicked = onSignupClicked;
    }

    private void userSignup(final String email, final String pass) {
        String url = "http://192.168.1.101/signup.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("LOG", "onResponse: "+response);
                onSignupClicked.onClicked(response);
                dismiss();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("LOG", "onErrorResponse: " + error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("pass", pass);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public interface OnSignupClicked {
        void onClicked(String email);
    }
}
```

And this my signup.php code :

```html
<?php
include "connect.php";
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$query = "INSERT INTO user(email,pass)VALUES (:email,:pass)";
$res=$connect->prepare($query);
$res->bindParam(":email",$email);
$res->bindParam(":pass",$pass);
$res->execute();

if($res){
    echo $email;
}else{
    echo "error";
}
```

**Please guide me how can i fix signup to connect with database :X**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server side code had bugs.  I fixed it

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','user') or die('connecition err');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (`email`,`pass`) VALUES ('$email','$pass')";

$query = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

if($query){
    echo $email;
}else{
    echo "no";
}


?>
```

Comment: I have to test my system to solve your problem. You can put this php code on a server for me to test???

Comment: this is my php address

Comment: what do you need?

Comment: I tested the Android section
And there was no problem and the response was well received.
I think the problem is in the inverter in the database.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
    VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."')";

Comment: dadash dorost nashod, age vaght dari va mozahem nistam beshe to teleg harf bezanim injori behtar mifahmam chikar konam, amatoram :))

Comment: id telegram: @javaddehban

Comment: mamnon, omadam :X